# Phonegap/Cordova platform independent background service

Tags: android, ios, cordova, background-service

We've been working on a mobile app using Phonegap/Cordova 3.3.0.

The problem we have now is that we really need a background service for this app which needs to run without opening the app itself.

I've found some services like https://github.com/Red-Folder/Cordova-Plugin-BackgroundService but all of these services seem platform dependent. The beauty of Phonegap is that the development is mostly platform independent.

Does anyone know of a background service which runs independent of any platform?
I think it's pretty hard to find such a service because IOS and android differ too much.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: It has been awhile. What did you decide to do? Did you abandon Cordova and learn native or did you find a solution for at least Android and iOS?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are right with you assumptions, unless anyone has developed the plugin yourself then looks like you'll have to do it yourself.

But I am not sure how to do this in iOS - I do not think it supports true multitasking?

However, remember that with Cordova/PhoneGap - the only reason it is truly cross-platform is because somebody before you wrote the bridges between native-to-JavaScript - so there is always going to be an element of native code in there somewhere.